# Show a group that is not abelian, but there is an element which is inverse to itself but isn't the neutral element

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

The question is:
Give an example of group that is not abelian,
that has an element which is inverse to itself,
and that element is not the neutral element.

What I've tried is:

supposing we have a group $G$ and elements x and y, $x*x=x$, $x*x\neq e$ and $y*y\neq y$. But, I have no idea what I should do from there.

EDIT: I don't know what dihedral group is, or any other symmetrical group as it was removed from our learning plan this year, So if there's any way to answer my request without dihedral group it would be really appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the  dihedral group $D_{2n}$? Think about $n \geq 3$.

Comment: In a group, $[x*x=x\land x\ne e]$ is impossible.

Comment: I assume that by "show a group..." you mean "give an example of a group..." If this is the case, all you need is a nonabelian group that has an element of order $2$, for example any finite nonabelian group with even order.

Comment: @Bungo yes, I meant give an example of a group.
So basically, all I need is a nonabelian group that has an element of order 2, for exmaple {2,4,6,8,10,12}, but this group is abelian. because if a = 2 and b = 4, then ab=8=ba=8.
So how can I do a nonabelian group with the element of order 2.

Comment: @MaxIlyouchenko The smallest nonabelian group is $S_3$, which has order $6$. This group has three elements of order $2$, namely the $2$-cycles $(12)$, $(13)$, and $(23)$ .They are all self-inverse.

Comment: @Bungo and none of them is the neutral element?

Comment: No, the neutral element has order $1$, but the three $2$-cycles have order $2$. If you are not familiar with $S_3$, another example is the multiplicative group of all invertible $2\times 2$ matrices, which is nonabelian and, for example, the matrix $\displaystyle -I = \begin{pmatrix}-1  & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$ has order $2$ and is therefore its own inverse.

Comment: @Bungo can you sum these $2$ examples up into an answer to finish the question? Thanks.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Sure, and if these examples are both unfamiliar to the OP, hopefully he can help us out by listing some nonabelian groups that he is familiar with!

Comment: Here’s some advice for you: you need to know not only theorems, but at least twice as many examples as theorems. Any nonabelian group of even order would have furnished an example of what you were looking for, I believe.

Comment: @Lubin will do it, fortunately, it's my last ever question regarding this subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summarizing my earlier comments:

You are seeking an example of a nonabelian group $G$ that has an element $g \neq e$ that is its own inverse. Equivalently, $g^2 = e$ and $g \neq e$, which is the same as requiring that $g$ has order $2$.

Here are two examples.

**Example 1.** Let $G = S_3$, the symmetric group consisting of all bijections of the set $\{1,2,3\}$. This is a nonabelian group of order $6$. It has three elements of order $2$, namely the three $2$-cycles $(12)$, $(13)$, and $(23)$. For example, $g = (12)$ swaps the set elements $1$ and $2$ and leaves $3$ alone. Therefore $g^2$ swaps $1$ and $2$ and then swaps them back, so $g^2$ is the identity. This means that $g \neq e$ and $g^2 = e$.

**Example 2.** Let $G = GL_2(\mathbb R)$, the multiplicative group of all invertible $2\times 2$ real matrices. This is a nonabelian group of infinite order. It has several elements of order $2$, for example the matrix
$$-I = \begin{pmatrix}-1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$$
satisfies $(-I)^2 = I$ and $-I \neq I$.

If these examples are not familiar, feel free to add a comment giving a few examples of nonabelian groups that you are acquainted with.

One additional remark: any *finite* nonabelian group with even order has an element of order $2$, by [Cauchy's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory)). I suspect that you do not yet know this theorem, but you will probably learn  about it soon. This shows that there many, many examples satisfying your requirements!

Answer (score 2):

A correct version of your statement is as follows:

*There is a nonabelian group, which has an element $g$ such that $g^{-1}=g$ but $g\neq e$*.

In fact, we may take the dihedral group $D_n$, $n\ge 3$, generated by a rotation $r$ and a reflection $s$, where $s=s^{-1}$, but $s\neq e$.

Comment: Well, actually, I was requested to give an example of non abelian group which has an element that is inverse to itself, but isn't the neutral element.
And, sorry, I haven't learned dihedral group so it's kinda hard for me to understand what it is.
Is there any group that I can give an example of without using the dihedral group?

Comment: The dihedral group is remarkably easy to understand though, and is one of the first nonabelian groups you will learn about (together with symmetry groups). Just think of it as the symmetries on the regular $n$-gon, which is $n$ rotations (including the identity) and $n$ reflections.

Comment: Max, the dihedral group $D_3$ is isomorphic to $S_3$, the symmetric group. If you don't know about these groups, it is really worth to learn it now.

Comment: @PacoAdajar Sadly, I haven't learned about it yet, and this question is my last mission to do regarding groups.
This year, they decided to remove symmetrical groups and dihedral groups.

Comment: Sounds like for a course of elementary number theory: " This year, they decided to remove prime numbers and even integers".

Answer (score 1):

You can take any nonabelian group $G$ and consider $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus G$. Voilà.